# is there a word for super general advice?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a single word or short phrase that roughly means: "super general advice"

Advice that is so general and obvious that it is not really useful.  To give some background I am a new hire at a very large company.  This morning the company hosted a meeting with the CEO where he gave some steps to success.  These steps included things like: "work hard" and "try to learn".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Platitudes....?

Comment: I would refer to it as "invaluable guidance for the simpleminded"—but not to the CEO. "Fatuous truisms" also springs to mind.

Comment: Oh—and I hope that your CEO didn't forget to say "Don't fall." That's always good advice.

Comment: [Bromides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromide_%28language%29)?

Comment: in general: generalization, over-generalization

Answer (score 5):

As I noted in a comment above, I think "fatuous truisms" fits the bill quite well, except that it's a two-word phrase. According to *Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1942):

> **Fatuous** does not necessarily or even often imply a pathological lack of intelligence, but it always implies the appearance of it and suggests a combination of foolishness, stupidity, and inanity.

A *truism*, according to *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003), has a similar sense of pointlessness:

> **truism** (1708) an undoubted or self-evident truth; *esp.* : one too obvious for mention.

One-word options include *banalities* and *bromides*.

*Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* does a nice job of distinguishing among various nouns of the *commonplace* family:

> A **commonplace** is a stock idea or expression which is frequently little more than the obvious, conventional, and easy thing to think or say on a given subject. ... **Platitude** adds to *commonplace* the idea of flatness or triteness and often, utterance with an air of importance or novelty. ... A **truism** is a self-evident truth; it differs from an axiom ... in frequently implying a somewhat superfluous insistence upon the obvious; as, Pope's palpable *truism* "The proper study of mankind is man." **Bromide** (a slang term) applies to any commonplace, platitude, or truism that strikes the listener or reader as especially dull or hackneyed and often, as evidence of its maker's low-grade mentality...

The remark about *bromide* being "a slang term " shows the age of this reference work; but otherwise, the distinctions it makes remain current, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious choices are (all definitions from the online Merriam Webster)

- [platitude](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/platitude) : a phrase or expression that has been used so often that it is no longer original or interesting
- [cliché](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cliche) : a phrase or expression that has been used so often that it is no longer original or interesting

You could also use

- [self-evident](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-evident) : clearly true and requiring no proof or explanation

Answer (score 2):

You might describe this type of advice as "common sense advice".

Answer (score -1):

Though two words, I would term it : Unvaluable counsel